# Why is the binding of the functor result with a new module name required to call nested functor of initial functor?

Tags: ocaml, functor

I have:

```
module Functor(M : sig end) = struct
  module NestedFunctor(M : sig end) = struct
  end 
end
```

This code is valid:

```
module V = Functor(struct end)
module W = V.NestedFunctor(struct end)
```

But this is invalid:

```
module M = Functor(struct end).NestedFunctor(struct end)
                          (*  ^ Error: Syntax error *)
```

As I understand, a functor is a relation between a set of input modules and a set of possible output modules. But this example confuses my understanding. Why is the binding of the functor result with a new module name required to call nested functor of initial functor?

My compiler version = 4.01.0

---

I'm new to OCaml. When I found functors I imagined something as

```
Engine.MakeRunnerFor(ObservationStation
                       .Observe(Matrix)
                       .With(Printer))
```

I thought it is a good tool for the human-friendly architecture notation.
Then I was disappointed. Of course, this is a syntax error and I understand that. But I think this restriction inflates grammar and makes it less intuitive. And my "Why?" in the main question is in the context of the concept of language.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

While I don't believe that this restriction is strictly necessary, it is probably motivated by certain limitations in OCaml's module type system. Without going into too much technical detail, OCaml requires all intermediate module types to be expressible as syntactic signatures. But with functors, that sometimes isn't possible. For example, consider:

```
module Functor(X : sig end) = struct
  type t = T of int
  module Nested(Y : sig end) = struct let x = T 5 end 
end
```

Given this definition, the type of the functor `Functor(struct end).Nested` can't be expressed in OCaml syntax. It would need to be something like

```
functor(Y : sig end) -> sig val x : Functor(struct end).t end  (* not legal OCaml! *)
```

but `Functor(struct end).t` isn't a valid type expression in OCaml, for reasons that are rather technical (in short, allowing a type like that would make deciding what types are equal -- as necessary during type checking -- much more involved).

Naming intermediate modules often avoids this dilemma. Given

```
module A = Functor(struct end)
```

the functor `A.Nested` has type

```
functor(Y : sig end) -> sig val x : A.t end
```

by referring to the named intermediate result `A`.

Comment: I don't think this can be the reason. Any functor application expression has a path, so the issue of unnamed functor arguments does not apply. I suspect the reason, if there is one, may be more to do with being explicit about side effects: people don't always realise functors have a run-time cost, and this restriction encourages people not to keep re-applying the same functor.

Comment: @LeoWhite, I don't understand what you mean with "any functor application expression has a path". `F(struct end)` is an example of a functor application that's not a path.

Comment: Sorry I was confused about what was not supported. I had thought the issue was with using a functor application as the argument to a functor. Actually this is supported, and it is only projecting a nested module from a functor application that is prevented. Given this I think your answer is almost certainly the reason.

Answer (score 2):

Using the terminology in the [manual](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml-4.01/names.html#module-path), types and the like (module types, class types, etc.) can be qualified by an *extended-module-path* where a qualifier can be a functor call, whereas non-types (core expressions, module expressions, classes, etc.) can only be qualified by a *module-path* where qualifiers have to be plain module names.
For example, you can write a type `Functor(struct end).NestedFunctor(struct end).t` but not an expression `Functor(struct end).NestedFunctor(struct end).x` or a module expression `Functor(struct end).NestedFunctor(struct end)`.

Syntax-wise, allowing *extended-module-path* in expressions would be ambiguous: the expression `F(M).x` is parsed as the constructor `F` applied to the expression `(M).x`, where `M` is a constructor and the `.` operator is the record field access operator. This won't ever typecheck since `M` is obviously a variant to which the `.` operator can't be applied, but eliminating this at the parser would be complicated. There may be other ambiguities I'm not thinking of right now (with first-class modules?).

As far as the type checker is concerned, functor calls in types designation isn't a problem — they're allowed. However the argument has to itself be a path: you can write `Set.Make(String).t` but not `Set.Make(struct type t = string let compare = … end).t`. Allowing structures and first-class modules in type expressions would make the type checker more complex, because of the way OCaml manages abstract types. Every time you write `Set.Make(String).t`, it designates the same abstract type; but if you write

```
module M1 = Set.Make(struct type t let compare = String.compare end)
module M2 = Set.Make(struct type t let compare = String.compare end)
```

then `M1` and `M2` are distinct abstract types. The technical way to formulate this is that in OCaml, functor application is applicative: applying the same functor to the same argument always returns the same abstract type. But structures are generative: writing `struct … end` twice produces distinct abstract types — so `Set.Make(struct type t let compare = String.compare end).t` ≠ `Set.Make(struct type t let compare = String.compare end).t` — generative types lead to a non-reflexive equality between type expressions if you aren't careful what you allow in type expressions.

Code generation wouldn't be impacted much, because it could desugar `Functor(struct … end).field` as `let module TMP = struct … end in Functor(TMP).field`.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can see, there's no deep answer. The reported error is a syntax error. I.e., the grammar of OCaml just doesn't support this notation.

One way to summarize it is that in the grammar for a module expression, the dot always appears as part of a "long module identifier", i.e., between two capitalized identifiers. I checked this just now, and that's what I saw.

Comment: I'm new in OCaml. When I found functors I imagined something as
`Engine.MakeRunnerFor(ObservationStation.Observe(Matix).With(Printer))` And I think: this is cool

Comment: Maybe the folks will add support for your proposed syntax in a later revision. In the meantime you can do what you want with a little extra coding. The OCaml module system *is* cool, it's nonpareil.

Comment: It's not quite that simple; see my answer.